# Lua session with limited C/C++ stack

Tags: multithreading, lua

I have to run Lua session safely in an embedded multithreading environment where the thread stack is pre-allocated and of a fixed size.

It is allowed to have the script failed at Lua level due to high C/C++ stack consumption.
It it not allowed to have the whole application crashed at C/C++ level.
I cannot rely on checks provided by LUAI_MAXCCALLS and MAXCCALLS.

What's the right way to check and prevent any potential stack overflow of the Lua session?
What's the right place where to implement such a check?

Comment: Can you rebuild Lua with suitable values of `LUAI_MAXCCALLS' and 'MAXCCALLS` ?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot. I have the stack size defined in bytes and I cannot change it. And there is no direct mapping from stack size to LUAI_MAXCCALLS and MAXCCALLS.

Comment: Could www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#4.2 (LUA_MINSTACK) be a solution for you?

Comment: Unfortunately LUA_MINSTACK controls Lua stack while I am dealing with C/C++ stack.

Comment: You would have the same problem if you were doing a pure C/C++ app with no Lua, right? You want to make one of the threads safely crash in case of memory consumption, while the rest continue.

Comment: If that is the case, then you need to find a way to detect and handle the stack overflow from C/C++, not from Lua. Let Lua die without doing anything at all in Lua, and handle the thread error on with the C/C++ multithreading library of your choosing.

Comment: @kikito: I know how to obtain the remaining C/C++ stack size. Perhaps I am looking for (preferably) a single place of the Lua source code where such check is sufficient in all situations. I also have to find the remaining stack size necessary to safely execute lua_error in such situations.

Comment: Well, the Lua stack is on the heap, so you need only concern yourself with the C stack. That's only going to grow when the Lua script calls into a C function. Presumably there's a common bit of code that's always called before Lua calls into C (a quick grep of the source suggests `luaD_precall` in `ldo.c`) where you can add code to check the C stack size and throw a Lua error to abort the script if you're getting low.

Answer (score -1):

You could wrap the C-functions to be called within an outer C-closure checking your C/C++ stack. The closure would contain an upvalue referencing the actual C-function to be called:

```
CFunctionThunk(lua_state* l)
{
    Check available stack space.
    if( available stack space < minimum stack space required )
    {
        panic(...);
    }
    else
    {
        actualFunction = retrieve upvalue;
        actualFunction(l);
    }
}
```

This will add the thunk's stack space required to the stack space required by the function actually to be invoked, but this should be small and constant. Also, before calling into Lua from the very beginning, you should ensure that the remaining C-stack space is at least large enough to contain your Lua VM and two of the C-function stack frames (thunk + actual). You could investigate the stack pointer in a debugger to find the amount of space required for the thunk and Lua VM, which should be (more or less) constant. The check for stack space could also be reduced to a thread-local counter which is incremented at the start of the thunk and decremented at its end.

Another possibility would be to enable a Lua debug hook on function calls, check for C-functions there and do the C-stack checking if needed. But this will likely degrade runtime performance as the hook will be called also for Lua-defined functions within your script.